# multiple files as a single track in a CUE sheet?

Tags: audio, cd

Skimmed the CUE spec and the documentation/examples on digitalx.org, but didn't see an answer to my specific question. Thanks for any help in advance.

I have several files which contain a number of music "sets" or performances. Some of the sets are split across the end of one file and the beginning of another.

Is it possible to create a CUE sheet that contains this information without breaking up a set into multiple tracks (set 1 part 1, set 1 part 2, etc)? My goal is for each set to be a single track in the CUE. I would very much prefer to keep each audio file separate and not merge them all together into a single large file.

Updated example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Both files are 10 min long:

```
FILE "FILE_01.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "SET 01"
      INDEX 01 00:00:00
      INDEX 02 03:00:00
      INDEX 03 06:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "SET 02"
      INDEX 01 09:00:00
FILE "FILE_02.wav" WAVE
      INDEX 02 00:00:00  (I also tried this as INDEX 01, 00, etc)
      INDEX 03 03:00:00
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "SET 03"
      INDEX 01 05:00:00
```

My goal is for the track `SET 02` to include the last minute of `FILE_01` and the first 5 minutes of `FILE_02`. I tried the suggestion by @michael and it didn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I updated my answer - I'm afraid that is not possible with the CUE format options

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INDEX command may be used to create regions within a track:

```
FILE "C:\MYAUDIO1.WAV" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
    INDEX 02 02:00:00
    INDEX 03 04:00:00
FILE "C:\MYAUDIO2.WAV" WAVE
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    INDEX 00 03:00:00
    INDEX 01 03:02:00
    INDEX 02 05:34:32
    INDEX 03 08:12:49
    INDEX 04 10:01:74
```

Unfortunately all indices are relative to the start of a specific file, so there is no way you can make Track 02 start with the last bits of another file than the one specified for Track 02.

The available CUE commands are as follows, and there is simply no way to specify an offset (only gaps/pauses before and after a track).

> ```
> CATALOG – A 13-digit UPC/EAN code.
> CDTEXTFILE – A path to a file containing CD-Text info.
> FILE – A path to a file containing audio data, and to which subsequent commands apply.
> FLAGS – Per-track subcode flag(s).
> INDEX – Per-track index(es).
> ISRC – Per-track ISRC(s).
> PERFORMER – Per-disc or per-track performer name for CD-Text data.
> POSTGAP – Amount of post-track silence to add.
> PREGAP – Amount of pre-track silence to add.
> REM – A remark/comment to be ignored.
> SONGWRITER – Per-disc or per-track songwriter name for CD-Text data.
> TITLE – Per-disc or per-track title for CD-Text data.
> TRACK – Type of track to create, and to which subsequent commands apply.
> ```
>
> ([Source 1](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Cue_sheet#Cue_sheet_commands), [Source 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_(computing)), [Source 3](http://digitalx.org/cue-sheet/examples/))

To accomplish what you want, you need to make a copy of the region in the first track that you want to use as start for the second (or split it into two). And set that up accordingly.